# c++ and operator precedences

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

I know this long string could be made easier to read but I don't want that!

I want to get the color of a pixel and I'm using SDL. Although this is not very relevant to the question...

http://www.gamedev.net/topic/502040-sdl-get-pixel-color/

http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlsurface.html

Shows that to get this color value, you do:

```
 Uint32 *pixels = (Uint32 *)surface->pixels;
  return pixels[ number ];
```

Well I don't have it just like that and I also wanted to try and grasp the whole operator precedence stuff..

I've tried a bit but I can't get it to work with the last []operator.

So... I got this:

```
vector<Class*>* pointer_To_A_Vector_With_Pointers;

Class.h: 
vector<Class2*>* get_Another_Vector(); 

Class2.h
SDL_Surface* sdlSurface; 

SDL_Surface.h
has the pixels-array 




Uint32 value =  *(Uint32*) (* pointer_To_A_Vector_With__Pointers[i]->get_Another_Vector()  )[i2]->sdlSurface->pixels;
```

and it should be equivalent to saying this:

```
   Uint32 *pixels = (Uint32 *)surface->pixels;
```

It works but only retrieves the very first color of the pixel array. But I want to achieve this (the [number] at the very end of the line ) :

```
Uint32 value =  *(Uint32*) (* pointer_To_A_Vector_With__Pointers[i]->get_Another_Vector()  )[i2]->sdlSurface->pixels[ number ];
```

In other words, I want the very last operator[] ,  `sdlSurface->pixels[numbers]` ,  included.

Comment: There you go: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

precedence of `[]` is higher then `*`, so:

```
 *pointer_To_A_Vector_With__Pointers[i]->get_Another_Vector()
```

should be:

```
 (*pointer_To_A_Vector_With__Pointers)[i]->get_Another_Vector()
```

as your variable name suggests.

Comment: @jrok do you mean it first expression give compilation error?

Comment: No, I mean that I didn't know it is valid.

Comment: @jrok :) well this is guess answer, let us OP try other I will delete my answer.

Comment: Hi, I'm not getting it to work but before I continue: I'm a bit confused, let me rephrase: my current version allows [i] to work ,the problem is the very last operator [number] which is shown on the last line of code in my opening post. ( I have also edited my question for a slightly better expalanation)

Comment: @optional tell me the declarations of `sdlSurface`  and `pointer_To_A_Vector_With__Pointers`

Comment: @jrok: Sure, `A[B]->C` is equivalent to `(*A[B]).C`, as long as `A[B]` is a pointer.

Comment: I've updated the question with a bit more specific on the declarations of the sdlsurface and such!

Comment: @optional according to declarations what I suggested is correct `sdlSurface->pixels[numbers]` is correct but `pointer_To_A_Vector_With__Pointers` has to be in parenthesis. are you getting warning is or compilation errors?

Comment: ( * pointer_To_A_Vector_With_Pointers)[i]->get_Another_Vector()[i2]->sdlSurface()->pixels[numbers]; is how the full line looks now and it Visual gives a compilation error, redlining the * in front of the pointer_To_A_Vector_With_Pointers and saying: no operator "*" matches these operands

Comment: @optional delete this comment and post again add space before and after `*` otherwise codify as `\`` code `\``

Comment: @optional write it: `(*pointer_To_A_Vector_With_Pointers)[i]->(*get_Another_Vector())[i2]->sdlSurface()->p‌​ixels[numbers];`